# MYSQL Join Query not deleting

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to get the below query to delete all rows by `id` however the query is running fine but its not executing - no errors or rows effected.  I have tripple checked all of the coloumn names in the tables and they are correct.

**MYSQL:**

```
DELETE c FROM campaigns c 
JOIN campaignsFroms f ON f.campaign_id = c.id 
JOIN campaignsRaw r ON r.campaignId = c.id 
JOIN campaignsSubjects s ON s.campaign_id = c.id 
WHERE c.id = 1582
```

Comment: Can you check that `SELECT * FROM ..` returns records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you want this:

```
DELETE c, f, r, s
FROM campaigns c LEFT JOIN
     campaignsFroms f
     ON f.campaign_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     campaignsRaw r
     ON r.campaignId = c.id LEFT JOIN
     campaignsSubjects s
     ON s.campaign_id = c.id 
WHERE c.id = 1582;
```

This will delete records from all the tables that are connected to the campaign.  The `LEFT JOIN` is to ensure that the rows are not removed from consideration by the joins.

Comment: The query in the question only deletes from `campaigns`. This query will delete from all 4 tables. Where does the question say that this is the desired result?

Comment: @Barmar . . . I got the idea that the OP wants to delete from all the tables.  One possibility is that nothing was deleted because of foreign key relationships.

Comment: Probably right since he accepted the answer. But it would be nice if we could get him to clarify the question first.